# How to dissable button when author_id(table event) != auth()->user(); but super admin can access the button

Tags: php, laravel

succes to dissable button when author_id didnt same with auth()->user() id. 
but why the super admin cannot access the button to, which is i give access to super admin. my super admin id is = 1.
I've tried
to write this code

```
@if($users->id == $superAdmin || $users->id == $currentUser->id)
```

here is my blade

```
<tbody>
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
        <?php $currentUser= auth()->user(); ?>
         <?php $superAdmin= '1' ?>
            @foreach($event as $events)
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <ul class="icons-list">
                                @foreach($user as $users)
                            @if($users->id == $superAdmin || $users->id == $currentUser->id)
                                <li class="text-primary-600"><button class="btn " type="submit" style="background-color: Transparent;background-repeat:no-repeat;border: none;cursor:pointer;overflow: hidden;outline:none;"><a href="{{ route('agenda.edit', $events->id)}}"><i class="icon-pencil7"></i></a></button></li>
                                <li><form action="{{ route('agenda.destroy', $events['id'])}}" method="post">
                                    @csrf
                                    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                                    <button onclick="return confirm('Anda yakin menghapus agenda ini?')" class="btn " type="submit" style="background-color: Transparent;background-repeat:no-repeat;border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none;"> <i class="icon-trash text-danger-600"></i> </button>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                            @else
                            <li class="text-primary-600"><button class="btn disable" onclick="return false" type="submit" style="background-color: Transparent;background-repeat:no-repeat;border: none;cursor:pointer;overflow: hidden;outline:none;"><a href="{{ route('agenda.edit', $events->id)}}"><i class="icon-pencil7"></i></a></button></li>
                            <li><form action="{{ route('agenda.destroy', $events['id'])}}" method="post">
                                @csrf
                                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                                <button onclick="return false" class="btn disable" type="submit" style="background-color: Transparent;background-repeat:no-repeat;border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none;"> <i class="icon-trash text-danger-600"></i> </button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                        @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php $i++ ?>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

here is my controller

```
  public function index()
    {
        //
        $event = Event::latest()->get();
        $user = Event::where('author_id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)->get(); 
        return view("backend.agenda.index", compact('event', 'user'));
    }
```

Comment: that's ok @lewis4u, he swapped back in the blade `@foreach($user as $users)` (uncommon I know and it makes it difficult to read the code)

Comment: Your variable $user is a Collection of `Event` - is it what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: solved thanks @ChristopheHubert

Comment: happy to be of any help 

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved 
delete 
this code on my controller

```
$user = Event::where('author_id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

and 'user' in compact

delete quotation marks blade.php

```
<?php $superAdmin= '1' ?>
```

delete

```
@foreach($user as $users)
```

change this code

```
@if($users->id == $superAdmin || $users->id == $currentUser->id)
```

into this

```
@if($currentUser->id == $superAdmin || $post->author_id == $currentUser->id)
```